# Add item to a dropdown and a text field in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been dealing with this problem for a long time. I currently have a function called "add ()" that allows me to add items to an array that feeds a dropdown and text fields. Every time I add a new item to the array, I add it empty:

```
$scope.aAnimals.push({"animal": ""})
```

This causes a problem with the dropdown, since the value of "animal" is equal to ""

```
<Option style="display: none" value=""> Select an animal </option>
```

Then the item is not added. Both "animal" and the dropdown value of the first option are empty strings. If you add a value for "animal", other than "" here it would work and would be added to the dropdown.

What I can do? I want the generated text fields to be empty, and the dropdown adds the item.

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model='obj.animal' id='animal' name='animal'  
    ng-options="opt as opt.animal for opt in aAnimals  track by opt.animal">
          <option style="display:none" value="">Select an animal</option>
  </select>

  <div ng-repeat='item in aAnimals'>
    <input type='text' value={{item.animal}} class='animal' />
  </div>


 $scope.obj = {}
 $scope.aAnimals=[{ "animal": "cat"},{ "animal": "dog"}]

 $scope.add=function(){
   $scope.aAnimals.push({ "animal": ""})
 }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/PRDp3a1bDJKtRmGR9GMY?p=preview

Comment: track by `opt.animal` is disallowing `""` value to be appear in `ng-options`

Comment: @PankajParkar sorry, i dont understand, Pardon my ignorance

Comment: @PankajParkar what can do I?

Comment: after removing track by `opt.animal` from `ng-options` it will work...

Comment: @PankajParkar yes, but the values in the dropdown, not will be, "cat", "dog"... will be "0","1"

Comment: @PankajParkar i need the animals values in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Let me verify what you need.
When the user click on the Add button, a new empty text box will be create in the page and a new empty option will be create in the drop down. When the user change the value in the text box, the drop down option will change.

In this case your need to modify the code like this.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model='obj.animal' id='animal' name='animal'  
  ng-options="opt as opt.animal for opt in aAnimals">
  <option style="display:none" value="">Select an animal</option>
</select>

<div ng-repeat='item in aAnimals'>
  <input type='text' class='animal' ng-model='item.animal' />
</div>
```

I removed `track by opt.animal` like Pankas said, and added `ng-model='item.animal'`, also don't need `value={{item.animal}}` since we use AngularJS 2-way binding.

Comment: yes, but the values in the dropdown, not will be, "cat", "dog"... will be "0","1",   i need the animals values in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly, just remove display none in option

```
 <option  value="">Select an animal</option>
```

I seen you are using jquery in Save functionality. We have jqlite in built in angular. Please check below code for save.

```
 var length = $scope.aAnimals.length;
 $scope.aAnimals[length-1].animal = 
 angular.element(document).find('.animal').eq(length-1).val();
```

Comment: but is necesary that the user select an option, for that is necesary "select an animal"